# Try to get blob data from Oracle by OCI routines but get error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: c++, oracle, blob, oracle-call-interface

I try to get blob data from Oracle by OCI routines.
I use the next code but the exceute statement gives ther error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
What do I wrong? Can anybody help me?
Thanks,
Kees Braaksma

```
void get_blob_data()
{
// The query
// The results of this methode 
// if errstring is empty, the blob data can be found in the 4th parameter.
// otherwise the error is given in errstring
CString csQuery;
csQuery.Format("BEGIN get_blob('%s','%ld',:ERRSTRING,:BLOB); END;", "20", 200);

//init
OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *)m_OCIEnvironment , (dvoid **)(&m_OCIStatement),
    (ub4)OCI_HTYPE_STMT, (size_t)0, (dvoid **)0);

//Prepare statement voor query
OCIStmtPrepare(m_OCIStatement, m_OCIError, (text *)(csQuery),
    (ub4)(strlen(csQuery)), (ub4)OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT);

// output variables
char *pszResult = (char*)malloc(256);
memset(pszResult, 0, sizeof(pszResult));
Blob *blob = new Blob();

m_pIndicator1 = malloc(sizeof(OCIInd));
m_pDefine1 = NULL;

OCIDefineByPos(m_OCIStatement, &m_pDefine1, m_OCIError, (ub4)1,
    (dvoid*)*pszResult,
    (sb4)256, SQLT_STR,
    (dvoid*)m_pIndicator1,
    (ub2*)0, (ub2*)0, (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT);

m_pIndicator2 = malloc(sizeof(OCIInd));
m_pDefine2 = NULL;
OCIDescriptorAlloc(m_OCIEnvironment, &blob, (ub4)OCI_DTYPE_LOB, (size_t)0, (dvoid **)0);

OCIDefineByPos(m_OCIStatement, &m_pDefine2,
    m_OCIError, (ub4)2,
    (dvoid*)blob,
    (sb4)-1, SQLT_BLOB,
    (dvoid*)m_pIndicator2,
    (ub2*)0, (ub2*)0, (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT));


iStatus = OCIStmtExecute(m_OCISrvCtx, m_OCIStatement, m_OCIError, (ub4)1, (ub4)0, 
    (OCISnapshot *)NULL, (OCISnapshot *)NULL, 
    (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT);

// results:
// iStatus = -1;
// Errorstring: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any OCIBindByName() calls.  OCIDefineByPos() is used when running SQL queries, which you aren't.

It's odd that you use a mixture of %s and bind variables in the PL/SQL call.  I think you want to use bind variables for all parameters.

One handy hint is to see how [ODPI-C](https://github.com/oracle/odpi) uses OCI.  For LOBs you can get either locators or data directly.  The latter is a lot faster, but limited to 1G.   It's arguably easiest to install Python and cx_Oracle, and run some samples e.g. [ReturnLobsAsStrings.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py).  You can trace the OCI calls in dpiOci.c.

There are some sample OCI programs (sadly not so accessible - your DBA may be able to install them), look out for cdemolb.c and cdemolbs.c

Comment: Hello Christopher,
Thanks for your answer!
I am using OCIDefineBypos(), because these two parameters are output parameters. sorry that I forgot to mention that!
Kees

Comment: Use OCIDefine* for queries, not for executing PL/SQL code.  You need to use OCIBindByPos or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Best Oracle-users,

Still have problems with getting a blob from Oracle. I use it so less.
Most of the time I copy some code and a new query is working fine.

I asked my collegue to change the function.
New the query is:

---

### select ngm_transactie_pck.get_checkout_blob('20','200') from dual

the result of this function is a blob.
So i programmed:

static  OCILobLocator *blob = NULL;
after OCIHandleAlloc() and OCIStmtPrepare() as in previous example i have:

OCIDescriptorAlloc(m_OCIEnvironment, &blob, (ub4)OCI_DTYPE_LOB, (size_t)0, (dvoid **)0);

CIDefineByPos(m_OCIStatement, &m_pDefine2,
    m_OCIError, (ub4)1,
    (dvoid*)&blob,
    (sb4)-1, OCI_DTYPE_LOB,
    (dvoid*)m_pIndicator2,
    (ub2*)0, (ub2*)0, (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT));

The call to OciDefineByPos() gives crash/stackoverflow.
What do I wrong?
Greetz,
Kees

Comment: Please update your original question or post a new one instead of 'answering' with a second question.